# Retrieving values from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-graphview

I have a table called *SPEED_TABLE*. It contains 2 fields

1. speed_id: which is an integer and it is auto-increment.
2. speed_score: which is a string.

I wish to add these values in a line graph using **Android Graphview** - speed_id being the values in the *x-axis* and speed_score in the *y-axis*.

However, when I tried to display the values in the *graphview*, nothing was shown. After minutes of debugging, I still can't seem to find the problem with my code.

This is my code. I appreciate your help. Thanks a lot!

```
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
DbHelper myHelper;

public StatsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stats, container, false);
    GraphView graph = (GraphView) view.findViewById(R.id.graph);
    myHelper = new DbHelper(getActivity());

    // line graph series
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series1 = new LineGraphSeries<>(getData());
    graph.addSeries(series1);

    return view;
}

private DataPoint[] getData() {

    //read data from db
    final String TABLE_NAME = "SPEED_TABLE";

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + SPEED_TABLE;
    SQLiteDatabase db  = myHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor      = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    DataPoint[] dp = new DataPoint[cursor.getCount()];
    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
        cursor.moveToNext();
        dp[i] = new DataPoint(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getInt(1));
    }
    return dp;
}
```

Comment: "After minutes of debugging..." LOL.

Comment: Add line (after line `cursor.moveToNext();`) as **`Log.d("GETDATA","Getting data from row " + cursor.getPossition() + " Column0 value=" + String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(0) + "Column1 value=" + String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(1)));`** Run, if there is nothing in log then no rows are in the cursor. If expected data is shown in the log then the issue is with how teh data is subsequently being used. If the data is not as expected then update the question detailing the issue.